# Machine Epsilon

Tags: java, precision

I was looking at a simple way to approximate Machine Epsilon in Java:

```
float machEps = 1.0f;

do
    machEps /= 2.0f;
while ((float) (1.0 + (machEps / 2.0)) != 1.0);

System.out.println( machEps);
```

This returns:

```
1.1920929E-7
```

However, when I remove the conversion to `float` in the `while` loop:

```
float machEps = 1.0f;

do
   machEps /= 2.0f;
while ( (1.0 + (machEps / 2.0)) != 1.0);

System.out.println( machEps);
```

I get:

```
2.220446E-16
```

I'm not quite sure why this is....my ***guess*** is that in the second case Java attempts to expand `machEps` from a `float` to a `double`.  However, I'm not sure if that is an accurate statement or if there is another reason why I get two different answers.

Comment: Note that even with the conversion to float, the division and addition are being done as double arithmetic. Is that what you intended?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`1.0` and `2.0` are `double`s.

Arithmetic between `double`s and `float`s will implicitly convert the `float`s to `doubles`.

You need to force the entire expression to use `float`s by adding the `f` suffix to all of your literals.

Comment: I just tried the second case and added the `f` suffix.  It worked as the first case.  I'm not sure why there is an unnecessary conversion to `float` then  if you could use the `f` suffix instead(example is off of Wikipedia).

Answer (score 3):

Are you looking for `java.lang.Math.ulp`?

> Returns the size of an ulp of the argument. An ulp of a double value is the positive distance between this floating-point value and the double value next larger in magnitude.

Comment: Very late comment, but this answer is not relevant to machine epsilon - see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_epsilon

Comment: Of course it is relevant. you do ulp(1.0).

Answer (score 1):

You can easily find the smallest float that is strictly greater than 1.0 using Math.nextUp(1.0f).